# How to (if possible) set the orientation of a CustomLabel in the Microsoft Chart Control?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, data-visualization

How to (if possible) set the orientation of a CustomLabel in the Microsoft Chart Control? By default, the labels are oriented perpendicular to the chartarea, I would like to rotate the Y-axis labels 90 degrees. This is my first question so I don't have enough reputation points to post a screenshot.

The CustomLabel type does not seem to have any angle/orientation property and, according to my tests, the LabelStyle property of the axes does not seem to apply.

This is the code I use to display the labels:

```
private void Init()
{
    chart1.Customize += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas.First();
        CustomizeAxis(chartArea.AxisX, 10, x => DateTime.FromOADate(x).ToString());
        CustomizeAxis(chartArea.AxisY, 5, x => Math.Round(x, 2).ToString(), 90);         
    };

   //...
}

private void CustomizeAxis(Axis axis, int numOfIntervals, Func<double, string> convertValue, int angle = 0)
{
    var pos = axis.Minimum;
    var intervalSize = (axis.Maximum - pos) / (double)numOfIntervals;
    var intervalOffset = (intervalSize * 0.5);
    var labels = axis.CustomLabels;

    labels.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfIntervals; i++)
    {
        var label = new CustomLabel(pos - intervalOffset, pos + intervalOffset, convertValue(pos), 1, LabelMarkStyle.None);
        label.GridTicks = (i == numOfIntervals ? GridTickTypes.None : GridTickTypes.All);
        labels.Add(label);
        pos += intervalSize;
    }

    axis.LabelStyle.Angle = angle; //Has no effect
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research (I overlooked the now obvious search keyword 'angle') I found the solution to my problem. It turns out that the LabelStyle settings only applies to CustomLabels on the first labelrow, for more details, see the following link: [CustomLabels Angle](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e694d2f1-9051-4faf-9cd1-8dcd6e558c34/custom-labels-angle-on-fast-line-chart).

I changed the code to:

```
var label = new CustomLabel(pos - intervalOffset, pos + intervalOffset, convertValue(pos), labelRow: 0, markStyle: LabelMarkStyle.None);
```